# how to paste number in decimal separated by comma in excel cell using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to copy a table in excel using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.** 
    My excel is in Spanish with "," as decimal separator

> Code:

```
Dim nSheet as integer = 1
Dim measureFile As String, measureFileText As String
Dim measureFilesPath as string = "E:\Test\"

objApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
objBook = objApp.Workbooks.Open(_myFileName)
//'objApp.Visible = True
objSheets = objBook.Worksheets

objSheets(nSheet).activate()
objSheets(nSheet).Range("E1:E211").NumberFormat = "0,000"
objSheets(nSheet).Range("A1").Select()

measureFile = measureFilesPath & "test.txt"
measureFileText = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(measureFile, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

//' Clear and copy a measureFileText to clipboard
Clipboard.Clear()
Clipboard.SetText(measureFileText)

Thread.Sleep(500)

//'Paste the measureFileText to sheet
objSheets(nSheet).Paste()
```

**My table data is in a test.txt file as this**

> Data

```
840 8754    834 3,66    0,965   0,31
850 8864    849 3,82    0,979   0,32
860 8974    856 3,89    0,984   0,33
870 9084    864 3,97    0,999   0,33
880 9195    879 4,12    1,018   0,34
890 9305    886 4,21    1,023   0,35
900 9415    893 4,3 1,038   0,36
910 9525    908 4,47    1,048   0,37
```

I use the clipboard to paste data, but I have not been able to obtain the cell with values ​​greater than 1,000 correctly.

```
850 8864    849 3,82    0,979   0,32
860 8974    856 3,89    0,984   0,33
870 9084    864 3,97    0,999   0,33
880 9195    879 4,12    1018,000    0,34
890 9305    886 4,21    1023,000    0,35
900 9415    893 4,3     1038,000    0,36
910 9525    908 4,47    1048,000    0,37
```

or this one

```
850 8864    849 3,82    0,979   0,32
860 8974    856 3,89    0,984   0,33
870 9084    864 3,97    0,999   0,33
880 9195    879 4,12    1.018   0,34
890 9305    886 4,21    1.023   0,35
900 9415    893 4,3     1.038   0,36
910 9525    908 4,47    1.048   0,37
```

If I open a new book in Excel and paste the copied table from a .txt file it works fine.

Even if I stop the debugging, after copying the table to the clipboard and paste it in another book, it works well. 
If I change my program to be visible the Excel sheet and paste manually works fine.

Can someone give me an idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

sorry I haven't enought reputation to comment and i'm not sure that this is an answer but you can try to force to use the SystemSeparator (if the system culture is in es/ES) :

```
objApp.UseSystemSeparators = true
```

or set the culture :

```
Dim ci As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("es-ES")
objApp.DecimalSeparator = ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
objApp.ThousandsSeparator = ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You may try a quick workaround, e.g. replace commas with dots before pasting:

```
measureFileText = measureFileText.Replace(",", ".")
```

Your approach in general has the flaw in that you let Excel decide how to split columns, how to convert numbers and even where on the sheet to paste the results. These setting may change when you open Excel next time.

I would parse the data myself and first store it in an array

```
Dim strLines() As String = measureFileText.Replace(Chr(13), "").Split(Chr(10))  
Dim nLines as Integer = strLines.Length()
Dim nColumns as Integer = strLines(0).Split({" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ).Length()
Dim Arr(,) as Object
Redim arr(nLines, nColumns)

For iLine as Integer =  0 to nLines - 1
    Dim Line as String = strLines(iLine)
    Dim Columns() as String =  Line.Split({" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )

    for iColumn as Integer = 0 to nColumns - 1 
         dim T as String = Columns(iColumn)
         dim N as Double = Double.Parse(T, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES"))
         Arr(iLine, iColumn) = N
    next
next
```

And then put them into Excel

```
objSheets(nSheet).Range("A1").Resize(Arr.GetUpperBound(0) + 1, Arr.GetUpperBound(1) + 1).Value = Arr
```

Answer (score 0):

This works when I just used first @gsimo83's suggestion adding:

```
objApp.UseSystemSeparators = true
```